# How can I transfer files from one HDD to another?

Tags: transfer

I have two HDD's installed in my PC with two OS viz. One is Ubuntu 20.04, and the other is Windows 10.

Would it be possible to send files and/or folders from Ubuntu to Windows?

Comment: Did you try copy-paste?

Comment: You need to make sure Windows fast start up is off. Generally better to use a shared NTFS data partition as typical mount of NTFS gives full view that Microsoft hides. I have accidentally moved critical files by clicking & moving too quickly and moving an entire system folder. If internal partition best to permanently mount in fstab with correct settings.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - Yes I did but not allowed to paste.

Comment: @User24601 No. This question dealt with two different PCs.

Comment: Of course it's *possible*. There are lots of ways: sshfs, samba, scp, ftp, and many more. As written, this question would require an entire book to answer authoritatively, so it's much too broad. There are already many books on network file transfer. Edit your question to ask a specific, answerable question ("*given situation X, what's the easiest way to transfer Y GB across a network*") or limit the question to a single method (*"How to I set up Samba?"*)

Comment: One imagines that "two OS viz" means two OS are active simultaneously. Either you have a VM or two different PCs. But that's a guess -- your description is unclear. Your description must be clear to the volunteers who want to help you. Clarifying in comments is nice, but less important that [fixing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285949/edit).

Comment: @user535733 Somehow or other I couldn't let you understand. Sorry. However, I have clearly stated that two OS installed separately in two HDD in same PC. Neither it is on VM nor two different PCs.

Comment: @oldfred - Thanks for your suggestion. By unchecking "Turn on Fast Startup" as described in askubuntu.com/questions/145902/… works for me. Now I can transfer files from Ubuntu to Windows, both the OSs installed in different HDDs in a same PC.